# Java Map with TimeToLive Associated with each key/value pair

Tags: java, hashmap, ttl

Recently I was asked (in an interview) to design `HashMap` with TTL associated with each key. I done it using similar approach given below but as per him this is not a good approach as this would need iteration on whole map and if map size is in million then this would be a bottleneck.

Is there any better approach to do the same? Moreover- He was only concerned that a thread is kept running in background though the next TTL is hours later.

```
class CleanerThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Initiating Cleaner Thread..");
        while (true) {
            cleanMap();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(expiryInMillis / 2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void cleanMap() {
        long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        for (K key : timeMap.keySet()) {
            if (currentTime > (timeMap.get(key) + expiryInMillis)) {
                V value = remove(key);
                timeMap.remove(key);
                System.out.println("Removing : " + sdf.format(new Date()) + " : " + key + " : " + value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `timeMap` you can have 'timeQueue` storing key, timestamp pair. Keep removing keys only till you find timed out keys. You don't have to go through rest of the keys.

Comment: They asked you to explicitely use `Hashmap` instead of `LinkedHashMap` ?

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to use a `LinkedHashMap` so that you could preserve the insertion order. Infact `LinkedHashMap` extends from a `HashMap`. If running a thread is the problem, then you could create a custom implementation of the map by extending the `LinkedHashMap`. Inside the class, override the `get` method.

**EDIT** : Based on onkar's comment. It is better to override the `get` instead of `put` as this would prevent retrieval of expired items.

```java
public class MyLinkedHashMap<K> extends LinkedHashMap<K, Date> {
    
    private static final long expiryTime = 100000L;
    private long currentOldest = 0L;

    @Override
    public Date get(Object key) {
        long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        if ((currentOldest > 0L) && (currentOldest + expiryTime) < currentTime) {
            // even the oldest key has not expired.
            return super.get(key);
        }

        Iterator<Map.Entry<K, Date>> iter = this.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<K, Date> entry = iter.next();
            long entryTime = entry.getValue().getTime();
            if (currentTime >= entryTime + expiryTime) {
                iter.remove();
            } else {
                // since this is a linked hash map, order is preserved.
                // All the elements after the current entry came later.
                // So no need to check the remaining elements if the current is not expired.
                currentOldest = entryTime;
                break;
            }
        }

        return super.get(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: put break in else clause. If current entry is expired then you want to check next entries too

Comment: @onkarruikar Updated. Thanks for pointing it out. I thought I had put a `continue` in the `if`

Comment: Also, instead of `put` do this in `get` method. You don't want expired values.. This way you won't have to keep a thread running as requested in OP.

Comment: @onkarruikar made another tweak as well

Answer (score 1):

Extending HashMap and it's Entry class and adding new entry for expiry time and override get method to return value only if expiry time is in past i.e expiryTime<System.getCurrentTimeInMilis()

Answer (score 0):

When you talk TTLs, and you want to access them by order of their TTL values, you should use PriorityQueue or PriorityBlockingQueue or HeapMaps (idk if Java has a HeapMap implementation tho).

Whenever you insert an item, it gets shuffled to its proper ordering position withing the Collection.

So if you only want to take out TTLs that have expired, you just check/take, and you will get the eariest expired first, and you keep check/take until you hit the first whose TTL has not expired yet. That's where you stop.
Because PriorityQueues guarantee that (if you did the compareTo functions properly) all elemets are sorted at all times, so after hitting the first un-expired entry, a) that entry will be closest to expiry and b) all the others will have a later expiry. The last item in the queue - independent of the sequence you put them there - will be the one with the latest expiry.